How unusual were the conservative forces in Newton's era?
Today, we know that the conservative forces are a big deal.  All forces find their origin in some conservative forces like gravity or electromagnetism.  The non conservative forces are, for the most part, approximations for networks of conservative forces that we treat stochastically.
When Newton was constructing his physics, how did he view these conservative forces?  Were they peculiar? Did he find them everywhere he looked?
I know a few decades later, they were important enough for Hamilton to pen his principle which ushered in the era of Lagrangian mechanics.  But what did these forces look like during the early days of calculus based physics?

The idea of conservative forces comes from understanding energy, which was not done until the 19th century. Leibniz and others worked on vis viva (kinetic energy) but were not close to understanding potential energy. As for Newton, the forces that he might have tried would be gravity, springs and other elastic forces.
